# download iframe content with python web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

https://anime-world.in/?trembed=0&trid=1930&trtype=2 This link contains just an iframe tag and I want to download the video linked in it. However, the src attribute takes me to a page that is inaccessible. I want to know how can I possibly download the video.
I have tried going to the source site (error 403) and I have also tried looking in the network panel, could not find anything there. Thanks for the help!
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this script how to download the video from the URL:

```py
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://anime-world.in/?trembed=0&trid=1930&trtype=2"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0",
    "Referer": "https://anime-world.in/",
}

with requests.session() as s:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")
    url2 = soup.iframe["src"]
    html_doc = s.get(url2, headers=headers).text
    link = re.search(r'file:".*?(http[^",]+)', html_doc).group(1)
    print(link)

    with open("file.mp4", "wb") as f:
        f.write(s.get(link, headers=headers, verify=False).content)

    print("Done.")
```

This prints:

```
https://6-yt5mQW3xieQHnfPa.server1cdn.xyz/link/AWI165B50FD/360/bb55f30227f8db11dcd19fef59fd6e5f/?sid=f3439234305d48ff7424333b2ca2de77

Done.
```

and saves `file.mp4` with video (it takes a little while to download it.)

Comment: I seem to get an error when I name the file as anything except "file.mp4", I was thinking of using this code inside a loop so that I can use a counter and save files episode wise numerically. Can you suggest a way that I can save the video file with a name other than file.mp4?

Comment: @ssomename If you have `counter` already, you can format the filename string, for example `with open("file_{}.mp4".format(counter), "wb") as f:`

Comment: I have added the output screenshot to the question, somehow I am only able to save the video file with the name file.mp4 and get this html text when I save with another name.

Comment: @ssomename It depends on the initial `url`, not on filename of the video file saved. What you've got it's probably some sort of captcha page. Check if `link` variable has correct URL to the video.

Comment: Thanks, just checked a few links manually, its an ad page that I am being redirected to sometimes, will run the script again on only these files till I download the video instead of a webpage.

Comment: Consider this video 

https://salam.alphaschool.ir/cyx67gkabj5d/iframe

It cannot be downloaded with above script.